# Get the count of female/male guests of a Facebook Event without Facebook API

Tags: facebook, events

I want to create a web application that shows the amount of female and male guests of a public Facebook Event. Now the tricky part is that I want to achieve this **without the help of a "Facebook App"**. Maybe this is possible through the Open Graph API?

Greetings

Comment: You can't get the gender of a person without them giving you access to it

Comment: @WizKid what do you mean? You must know that I am not trying to get the gender of a specific person - I want to know the genders of ALL participants.

Comment: What do you even mean by _“Open Graph API”_ …?

Answer (score 0):

This is how public event looks like for not authorized user:
[image]

And this is when I click on guests:

[image]

So no, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Facebook allows you to retrieve the 'Basic' information set about a user - that is, information available without providing an access token (including gender).

But you will need an access token to be able to get attending users of an event, however if the event has privacy set to OPEN you should be able to retrieve the attending users with **any** access token.

From [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event/attending):

```
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{event-id}/attending'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

Then simply check the gender field from the users objects.